# Passing parameters to MVC controller via JavaScript AJAX GET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to pass a collection of data to my C# controller via AJAX from JavaScript.  The data being passed will not always be the same.  There is no create/update/delete to the system happening at all this is purely a read operation.

My object looks like this:

```
values = {
    Id: [SOME INT ID],
    DB: [SOME DB ID],
    Values: [{collection of values}]
}
```

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "MYURL?" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(values)),
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data){
        // do callback stuff
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

My controller is:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyController(DataViewModel viewModel){
    // Stuff and Things code
}
```

The data is not being populated in the controller in the viewModel at all.  All the values are null.  How can I pass the JSON data into the controller?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is the variable name in your `url` in your ajax method?

Comment: Have you tried using `$.ajax({ ... data: values })` instead of stringifying them? I'm pretty sure jQuery will encode the parameters for you.

Comment: show `DataViewModel` and the `{collection of values}` code. @Pluto has the correct advice in the comment above.

Comment: Yeah we definitely need to see the full model or an example of the data you're sending to the server. While jQuery can easily convert basic values in an object to be included in a request, having nested objects could be problematic. Some of your data in `values.Values` might not be sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax call should be the following instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "MYURL",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data){
        // do callback stuff
    },
    data: values
});
```

Some issues that existed in your code include that you used a semi-colon instead of a comma at the end of the `url:` line and `dataType:` sets the response data type (not the request data type, which is sent to the server).